# Specify the .dockerignore path in docker-compose or command line?

Tags: docker, dockerignore

Dockerignore: can you specify the path of dockerignore file in docker-compose or command-line?

For the following directory structure:

```
/root/path/        <---- build context path
    sub-project1/
    sub-project2/
    sub-project3/
    root-project/
         .dockerignore
         Dockerfile
```

If .dockerignore is put under the /root/path/, it will be outside of all projects and could not checked into source contorl(e.g., git).

Ideally, it should be put under the root-project/, but it is not the build context. Is there a way to specify the file path of the .dockerignore file that will be applied to the whole build context? e.g.,

```
 docker build -f root-project/Dockerfile
     --dockerignore=root-project/.dockerignore
     -t image:tag  /root/path
```

docker-compose:

```
 services:
   web:
     build:
       dockerignore: root-project/.dockerignore
```

Dockerfile:

```
 FROM scratch
 WORKDIR /app/my_project
 # copy all projects
 COPY . .
 // build project
```